# ASP.NET Core Failed AJAX Post Request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I've been trying to pass an object of information to .NET Core Controller method. Passing a single string and receiving is fine.
But, when I try to pass data fetched from a table, the controller is not receiving.
See the code below.

**Console Error Output**

```
POST https://localhost:44366/home/GetInformation 415
```

**MVC Controller :** Tried [FromQuery] also. It gets the hit successfully but receives null.

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string GetInformation([FromBody]Student student)
    {
        return "Hi " + student.Name;
    }
}
```

**JQuery AJAX :**
I've tried putting Raw object, sending objects directly as data

```js
var fetcheddata = {
    Id: col1,
    Name: col2
};

$.ajax({
    url: "home/GetInformation",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(fetcheddata),
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    success: function (data, status) {
        //task
    },
    error: function (data, status) {
        //task
    }
});
```

Although, using **Fiddler** with these params, it is working fine.

```
POST https://localhost:44366/home/GetInformation HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:44366
Content-Length: 28

{"Id": 1, "Name":"Cucumber"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `Content-Type` header on your AJAX request, you can see it is present in your Fiddler request.

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  contentType: 'application/json'
  ...
});
```

The default content type for [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`.

The error you're receiving is [HTTP 415 - Unsupported Media Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415).

Comment: The contentType with datatype conversion solved my problem. `var fetcheddata = {
            Id: parseInt(col1),
            Name: col2.toString()
        };`